# Let $c : P(N) \rightarrow Z$ be the function defined by $c(X)= -1$ if $X$ is empty and $c(X)$ equals the least element in $X$ if $X$ is not empty.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $c : P(N) \to Z$ be the function defined by $c(X) = -1$ if $X$ is empty and $c(X)= \min(X)$ if $X$ is not empty.

(a) What is $c(\{5,15,22\})$?

(b) What is $c(\{x : x \in N$ and $x$ is an odd prime number $\})$

(c) Is $c$ one to one? Explain?

(d) What is the range of $c$? Explain.

For part a) For this question $x=\{5,15,22\}$. So $c(\{5,15,22\}) = 5$. Does least element mean smallest element? If so in that case $5$ should be the correct answer.

For part b) $x$ is an odd prime number that only falls in the set of natural numbers $N$. How should i show this answer as it's going to be infinite. Is this okay $\{1,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23....\}$?

For part c) I dont know. How would I do this?

For part d) If we put the whole range of the natural number $N$ in the function $c$ then $c(N) = 0$. This means for the Domain $N$ we get the codomain $0$. So isn't $0$ the range?

Comment: For (b), normally we don't consider $n=1$ to be a prime number. For (c), one-to-one means that if $X\neq Y$, then $c(X)\neq c(Y)$. Can you think about an example of two different sets $X,Y\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $c(X)=c(Y)$? If so, then the function is not one-to-one. For (d), remember that the range is the set of all possible values that the function can take. So, is there a subset $X\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $c(X)=1$. What about $c(X)=2$, or $c(X)$ for an arbitrary $n$?

Comment: I know what one to one means. But in this question if it is one to one that means for every P(N) elements put into the function will give every value of Z. P(N) means 2 to the power of number of all the elements present in N.But isn't P(N) infinite? So how do I go on about understanding that what P(N) is?

For part d) How can it be 1 or 2? If we put the natural numbers N in it won't it always be 0?

Comment: $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ represents the collection of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$, and $c$ is a function that transforms a subset of the natural numbers into an integer, by taking the minimum of the set. As you pointed out, $c(\{5,15,22\})=5$, and, for instance, $c(\{1,5,15\})=1$. Similar examples will prove that the range of $c$ is the set $\{0,1,2,\ldots\}=\mathbb{N}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: On the other hand, if you really know what one-to-one means, you probably know that it does not mean that when applying the elements of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})$ it will give every value of $\mathbb{Z}$. I think  you are confusing "one-to-one" with "surjective".